# Shell not finding commands after I changed my .bash_profile file

Tags: terminal, macos, bash, ssh

I was following a tutorial trying to install Laravel (5.0). The tutorial showed to add `export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel"` to the `.bash_profile` document. Since then, I am not able to execute any command (nano, ssh, etc).

Nothing happens when I executed this in terminal:

```
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel"
```

My `.bash_profile` looks like this:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin:$PATH
```

I tried logging out, restarting and entering the following commands:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
. .bash_profile
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you did:

```
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel"
```

You changed the system default `PATH` to something nearly useless. You should never *replace* `PATH`, you should only *append* to `PATH`.

Remove the following two lines from your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin:$PATH
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel"
```

And replace them with the following:

```
pathadd() {
    if [ -d "$1" ] && [[ ":$PATH:" != *":$1:"* ]]; then
        PATH="${PATH:+"$PATH:"}$1"
    fi
}
pathadd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin
pathadd ~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel
export PATH
```

This is a safe way to append to your `PATH` environment variable. It only does the append if the path isn't already in the list.

Comment: I did as you suggested however, I am still not able to use nano or SSH commands.

Comment: You have to quit existing shell sessions and start new ones. Or run: `source ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Ah ha! I had to quit Terminal after using `source ~/.bash_profile`. Now everything works. Thank you!

Comment: Why bother having `pathadd`? Just do like Lukas Bestle said.

Comment: Lukas' answer is dangerous if you end up in a situation where you have sub-shells that re-read your `.bash_profile` -- you get overlong PATH env vars and that can be both problematic for predictable executable locations and for path searching speed.

Answer (score 1):

What you did is to overwrite the `PATH` variable. This removed every other path that was in your `PATH` before from the variable.

You need to do the following:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

This *adds* the Composer bin path to the system paths where SSH etc. are located.

Comment: `~` won't be expanded to the user's home folder if it's in quotes (even double-quotes). Either use `export PATH=~/".composer/vendor/bin/laravel:$PATH"`, or `export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel:$PATH"`